# .NET 4.5 C# | NewTonSoft JSON

Tags: c#, .net, json, классы, объекты

```
RootObject root = new RootObject();
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root, Formatting.Indented);
```

В итоге получаем

> {
>       "Billing": null,
>       "Payment": null }

А не это

```
{
  "FirstName": "123123",
  "LastName": null,
  "Email": null,
  "Telephone": null,
  "Address": null,
  "City": null,
  "State": null,
  "Country": null,
  "Zip": 0
},
  "PaymentType": null,
  "CardNumber": null,
  "CVV": 0,
  "ExpYear": 0,
  "ExpMonth": 0
}
}
```

[image: 1]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас нету инициализации объектов, которые вы хотите сериализировать.

Вы пишите:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public Billing Billing {get; set;}
}
```

Вы грубо говоря сказали: "*Здесь у меня должен быть объект типа `Billing` и назвать его надо также, `Billing`*". Ок, представим, что у нас там будет `public string Billing {get; set;}`, что тогда? Верно, у нас будет `NULL` объект, ибо мы его не инициализировали и не задали ему каких либо данных.

Получается, для того, что бы в объекте были данные, его надо инициализировать, то есть в вашем случае это:

- Либо:

  ```
  public Billing Billing {get; set;} = new Billing();
  ```
- Ну или:

  ```
  RootObject root = new RootObject();
  root.Billing = new Billing();
  ```
- Или если класс `Billing` изначально пустой, то:

  ```
  Billing billing = new Billing();
  billing.FirstName = "123123";
  RootObject root = new RootObject();
  root.Billing = billing;
  ```

**Итог:** Вы отдаете сериализации пустые классы, которые не как не инициализированы, что равнозначно значению `NULL`.